# Help understanding wiring of capacitor

Tags: capacitor, wiring

I just wanted to double check my understanding of the diagram as in my mind the "visual clues" related to the way the cap is drawn seem to contradict the actual instructions of the diagram.

If this capacitor only had 2 connectors on it  would it be correct to wire the neutral (black) terminal to the neutral (black) wire?

From a logical POV would I have a single connection joining neutral black, neutral terminal and capacitor to the 1 leg of the capacitor, and the capacitor/grey wire to the other leg?

Another, simpler way of asking this - should all the black wires be connected together on 1 terminal and the grey one on the other?

Assuming the aerator to be a standard single phase AC motor, if the connection is fused (and has an RCD on it), and if the wiring were round the wrong way, would turning the motor on simply trip the fuse or could it damage the motor or capacitor?

[image: Circuit Diagram]

In the picture of the Capacitor below, the 2 lugs on the left are connected together and the 2 on the right.   (This looks to me to be 90 degrees to the way it has been drawn in the diagram)

[image]

Comment: A picture of the actual equipment might be better than the diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is what you have there. As long as you have the capacitor in series with at least one motor winding, you should damage anything. If you look at the top terminals on the capacitor, you should see that they make up a small terminal block on each side. This is often used as a way to eliminate the need for additional connectors. In you case, it looks like this is done on the neutral side. Take care when working with mains power. Safety is your friend.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUAMpH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time.  I've added a pic of the cap.   Its difficult to add a picture of the aerator, but really its just a moter with a cable with 4 wires coming out - the wires are colored as per the diagram,

Comment: You wrote: `you should damage anything`. Surely you mean `you shouldn't damage anything`?